Curves on a trousers space.
How does one go about defining curves on a trousers space? I want to define two curves evolving cyclically around a cylinder and then at some time let one of the curves evolve on the other cylinder. How do I do this?

I‘ll take the image of a trouser literally and the practical point of view here :), but the setup of your question is not clear.
But also see the Pair of Pants (Mathematics) Wikipedia article. You define curves like on any other space, so nothing fancy, but you probably want to see how much you would have to do to get your hands dirty.
One way: You need something like a coordinate indicating the height (supposing that the trouser is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$).
Let us take the usual choice of coordinates $(x,y,z)$ with $z$ being this height. After you parametrized you surface, i.e. $$E(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$$ you can just take a curve $(u(t),v(t))$, s.t. you obtain that $z$ is at the height where both are joint and then let $(x,y)$ run to the other side.
Example:
Define $$C(X,Y,H,R) = \{(x,y,z)|(x-X)^2+(y-Y)^2 = R^2 \land 0\leq z\leq H\}$$
as a cylinder and the rectangle $$\tilde{C}(X,Y,Z,L_X,L_Y,L_Z) = \{(x,y,z)| 0 \leq x - X \leq L_X \land … \land 0\leq z-Z\leq L_Z\}.$$
We can now define a bad version of the pants $P$ by placing them accordingly, i.e. let $$P = C(-1,0,1,1/2) \cup \tilde{C}(0,0,1,3/2 + 3/2,1,1) \cup C(1,0,1,1/2).$$
Any now a curve on the pants $P$ is given by $$\gamma_{1}(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 (1/2 \cos(0) - 1,1/2 \sin(0), t) &, 0\leq t \leq 1 \\
(t-1/2-1,0,H) &, 1<t<2\\
(1/2 \cos(-\pi) + 1, 1/2 \sin(-\pi), 1-(t-2)) &, 2<t<3
\end{array}\right.$$
To get a circular motion, just put another function into $\cos,\sin$ and be aware that in this example you traverse the bottom. Now just apply homeomorphism/diffeomorphisms to $P$ and the curve to smooth the shape.
Disclaimer: I probably messed up some numbers.

thank you so much for this answer. this has cleared up a lot of things for me.

This was rather an entertaining answer.
